# Parse through a string and add entries to a list

Tags: java, list, parsing

I have a string with content in it between separators. The string would look this for example:

```
a
xxxxx
b xxxxx c xxxxx d xxxxx
```

So I want to parse it to extract a, b, c, d, etc. and add each of them to a list so I can access each one separately later. How can I go about doing this? Thank you

Comment: Is is multi-line string?

Comment: Are you asking us how to read every second word?

Comment: So every `xxxxx` is the same, right?

Comment: I think `xxxxx` is the content that should go into the list.

Comment: We need more informations about your actual input. Is `xxxxx` always same word? How can `a` `b` `c` `d` words look like? Is your example multiline? What is relationship between parts you want to find and `xxxxx`?

Comment: yes every xxxxx is the same. a b c d are different URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you.

- replace all `xxxxx` with empty string.
- split based on space.

sample code:

```
String s="a\nxxxxx\nb xxxxx c xxxxx d xxxxx";
List<String> list=Arrays.asList(s.replaceAll("xxxxx", "").split("\\s+"));
System.out.println(list);

String[] array=list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

output:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

---

#### EDIT

As per @Pshemo  you can combine both in single step.

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*\\bxxxxx\\b\\s*"));
```

Comment: Instead of `replaceAll("xxxxx", "").split("\\s+")` you can use `split("\\s*\\bxxxxx\\b\\s*")`.

Comment: All this does is remove the xxx. It is still in one big string I want a to be in the first index of the list, b in the second and so on and so on.

Comment: sorry don't understand what you want to achieve? do you need array if yes then convert List into array. `String[] array=list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`

Comment: @user3218114 how do you like my answer?

Comment: @KickButtowski As per the sample input, It's multi-line  hence I used `\s` that matches `[\r\n\t\f ]` hence all the conditions are handled. one more thing I considered `xxxx` as separate word that is matched using `\b` as word boundary.

Comment: @user3218114 I updated my answer could you tell me what you think? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `str.split();` method

An example would be:

```
String x = "axxxxbxxxxc";
String[] arr = x.split("xxxx");
// arr[0] would be a
// arr[1] would be b
// arr[2] would be c
```

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @Zach some people are like it just down voting without providing any reason. Cuz I am sure you do not care about the vote, you just wonder what is wrong with your answer in oder you can learn

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: I used regular expression to split the String.

`\\sx+\\s`  if the word start with a blank follow by whatever number of x and end up with a blank

or

```
 x+ the words consist of whatever number of x
```

**Code**:

```
    String s = "a"
            + "xxxxx"
            + "b xxxxx c xxxxx d xxxxx";

    String[] sp = s.split("\\sx+\\s|x+");
    for (String sp1 : sp) {
         System.out.println(sp1);
    }
```

**Output**:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Surely you can add a little explanation?

Comment: @DennisMeng does it answer what you want? I will add some explantion for you later just I wanna know if it helped you?

Comment: I found your post through the review queues, it probably got put there because code-only answers hit a bit of a gray area. I personally am not a big fan of them because they do much less for people who want to use the question as a learning experience and can also encourage too much "just copy paste this and don't think about it" mentality.

Comment: @DennisMeng do you like my explanation ?